# "Tick is not defined" error on Firefox, using d3

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, d3.js

I am new to both d3 and web programming generally. I have put together a force layout graph based on  https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1153292. The graph works fine in Safari, Chrome and Opera (I haven't checked IE yet).However when I try to use it in Firefox I get the error "Tick is not defined".I am using Firefox 12.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated
Thanks, 
Claire

(The code is a js script file and is triggered on a mouse click, the force layout part is below.).

```
d3.csv("data/sharing.csv?r1",  function(error, data) {
                    dataset = data
                    var nodes = {};

        dataset.forEach(function(link) {
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] =    {name:link.source});
        link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
        });


        var w = 500;
        var h = 600;

                         var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
            .links(dataset)
            .size([w-10,h-10]) 
            .linkDistance(60) 
            .charge(-375) 
            .on("tick", tick)
            .start();

        //Draw svg canvas
        var svg = d3.select("#svgContainer").append("svg").attr("id", "viz").attr("width", w).attr("height", h)

        // Create arrowheads
        svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
            .data(["end-arrow"])
            .enter()
            .append("svg:marker")
            .attr("id", String)
            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 15)
            .attr("refY", -1.5)
            .attr("markerWidth", 6)
            .attr("markerHeight", 6)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
            .attr("fill", "black") 
            .append("svg:path")
            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

        //Add links between the nodes and draw arrowhead at end of it.
        var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
            .data(force.links())
            .enter()
            .append("svg:path")
            .attr("stroke-width",2)
                        .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("fill","none")
            .attr("marker-end", "url(#end-arrow)");

        //Draw circles for nodes
        var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter()
            .append("svg:circle")
            .attr("r", 6)
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .call(force.drag)
            .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
            .on("mouseout", fade(1))

        //Label the nodes/circles
        var text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")

        text.append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", 8)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; })

        function tick() {
          path.attr("d", function(d) {
            var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
          });

          circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });

          text.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });
        }


=============REPLY TO COMMENT == FULL SCRIPT INCLUDING CALL TO CSV===

//If sharing button is clicked, load sharing data
d3.select("#sharing").on("click", function() {
d3.csv("data/sharing.csv?r1",  function(error, data) {
if (error)  
{//If error is not null,(i.e : something goes wrong), log the error.                            
window.console.log(error);      
} 
else 
{//If file loaded correctly, log the data to the console.   
dataset = data
window.console.log(dataset) 
color = getColor()
vizType = "force";

//Hide date fields/buttons as they are not applicable 
d3.select("#instructions").classed("hidden", true);
d3.select("#instructions2").classed("hidden", false);
d3.select("#startLabel").classed("hidden", true);   
d3.select("#startDate").classed("hidden", true);    
d3.select("#endLabel").classed("hidden", true); 
d3.select("#endDate").classed("hidden", true);  
d3.select("#removeFilter").classed("hidden", true); 
d3.select("#sharing").classed("hidden", true);
d3.select("#showData").classed("hidden", false);
d3.select("#showData").attr("value", "Back to Circles Vizualization");
d3.select("#tipsData").classed("hidden", true); 
d3.select("#ncpData").classed("hidden", true);      
d3.select("#tipsNCPData").classed("hidden", true);
d3.select("#tipsLabel").classed("hidden", true);    
d3.select("#ncpLabel").classed("hidden", true);     
d3.select("#tipsNCPLabel").classed("hidden", true);  

//Clear the previous viz and data
d3.select("#viz").remove();
d3.select("#stageTable").remove();
d3.select("#userTable").remove();

//Gets a count of sender records/source and stage/type          
var senderCount = getSortingCount(dataset,"Sender");
var stageCount = getSortingCount(dataset,"Stage");

//create tables summarising results
var summarySenderTable = tabulate(senderCount, ["Shared", "Sender"], vizType);  
var summaryStageTable = tabulate(stageCount, ["Shared", "Stage"], vizType);

var nodes = {};

// For each datapoint, check if a node exists already, if not create a new one. 
dataset.forEach(function(link) {
link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] ={name: link.source});
link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

//Set the width and height for the svg, that will display the viz
var w = 500;
var h = 600;

var force = d3.layout.force()
          .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
          .links(dataset)
          .size([w-10,h-10])  
      .linkDistance(60) 
      .charge(-375) 
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

//Draw svg
var svg =    d3.select("#svgContainer").append("svg")
.attr("id","viz").attr("width",w).attr("height", h)

// Create arrowheads
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
          .data(["end-arrow"])
          .enter().append("svg:marker")
          .attr("id", String)
          .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
          .attr("refX", 15)
          .attr("refY", -1.5)
          .attr("markerWidth", 6)
          .attr("markerHeight", 6)
          .attr("orient", "auto")
          .attr("fill", "black") 
          .append("svg:path")
          .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

//Add links between the nodes and draw arrowhead at end of it.
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
     .data(force.links())
     .enter()
     .append("svg:path")
     .attr("stroke-width",2)
     .attr("stroke", function(d){return color(d.ScreenName)})  
     .attr("fill","none")
     .attr("marker-end", "url(#end-arrow)");

//Draw circles for nodes
var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
       .data(force.nodes())
           .enter()
           .append("svg:circle")
           .attr("r", 6)
       .attr("fill", "white")
       .attr("stroke", "black")
       .call(force.drag)
       .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
       .on("mouseout", fade(1))

//Label nodes/circles
var text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
          .data(force.nodes())
      .enter()
      .append("svg:g")  
       text.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", ".31em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })  

//Set radius for arrows and applies transform 
function tick() {
   path.attr("d", function(d) {
   var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
       dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
       dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
   return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +   d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
   });

   circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
   return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
   });

   text.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
   });
}   
//Allow for filter by row on stageTable
d3.select("#stage").select("#stageTable").selectAll("tr")
          .on("click", function(d){
          d3.select(this)
          var rowText = this.childNodes[1].innerHTML
          var svg = d3.select("#svgContainer").select("svg")
          var path = svg.selectAll("path")
                .style ("opacity", 1)
                .transition()
                    .duration(250)
                .style ("opacity", function(d){
          if(d.ScreenName == rowText){  
                      d3.selectAll("marker path").transition().style("stroke-opacity", 1);
          return fade(1)    
          }
         else{
        d3.selectAll("marker path").transition().style("stroke-opacity", 0.1);
          return 0.1
          })
        d3.select("#removeFilter").classed("hidden", false);                
          })

//Checks what links are connected to which(used for mouseover) 
var linkedByIndex = {};
dataset.forEach(function(d) {linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;});

function isConnected(a, b) {
return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] ||     a.index == b.index;
}
                                                        //Fades in/out circles and arrows on mouseover.
function fade(opacity) {
return function(d) {
circle.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
return thisOpacity;
 });
path.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
 });

};
}       

}   
})

})

Accessor for colour
function getColor(){
return color
}
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. As an experiment, does moving the declaration of tick above where it is passed in to on() make a difference? Can you post the rest of the code containing the d3.csv call somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried moving the tick function around but there was no change. It just told me something else was undefined (circle was undefined, I tried moving circle and then svg was undefined...this went on until I was back to tick being undefined)I have posted the full script above, I hope it is OK, like I said I am new to programming so please do say if you see any big faux pas. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the entire source code helped to clarify things.  There is an if/else statement at the very top that checks for an error.  The entire rest of the code is inside the else block.  This is what's causing the problem.

Function declarations (such as tick() in your case) have browser-specific weird behaviour when defined inside conditional blocks.  [Here's a pretty good write-up](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) that explains the differences between *function declarations*, *function expressions* and the ill-defined and inconsistently supported *function statements* (which is what you've inadvertently created with so much code living in an else block).

If you pull the code out of the else block, I think the behavior should be more predictable across browsers.

In general, it's not good programming practice to create enormous, long conditional blocks.  Not only does it introduce the possibility of these types of errors but it can be very difficult to read and understand.  Same thing goes for very deeply nested conditions.

Try to keep your conditions fairly tight so that the code living inside the conditional blocks corresponds directly to the meaning of the condition itself.  You should be able to read the intention of condition and block contents out loud and they should make sense together.  As much as possible, code that doesn't have to do with the condition should be at the top level of the function containing it.  You can increase readability by factoring your code into meaningful functions and keeping conditions under control.

In your example above, you could do:

```
if (error) {                            
    window.console.log(error);      
} 
else {
    window.console.log(dataset);
}

dataset = data 
color = getColor()
vizType = "force";
...
... rest of code
```

One final comment is that a tool like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) to validate your code.  It would point out problems like this automatically.  It can be overly strict sometimes but its a good learning experience to at least understand what it's complaining about.